# How to Create Directory in Phone Memory in android Emulator in Android

Tags: android, directory, emulation

I want to create Directory in phone memory in android Emulator in android..
how to create directory in phone memory in android emulator not in SDCard

Answer (score 0):

Following code can help you to create directory in phone's internal memory:

```
    File f = new File(getFilesDir()+"/abc");
    if(!f.isDirectory())
        Log.d("dir", f.mkdir()? "Directory created": "Directory not created");
```

Actually **getFilesDir()** returns path to internal memory's `file` folder and allows you to create further files and/or directories inside.